# QWebView and local html page

Tags: html, qt, qwebview

Good day. In version 4.7.4 loading my local page in QWebView working good, but after update Qt version to 4.8.2 my local page loaded, but nothing happened.
 I look to examples sources of Qt, and a see that new Qt version work with local page and load this page successfully, but this page was very simple.
 As for me,i have page where used jquery script, may be this trouble of my page loading process?
Code of my local page.

```
<html><head>
<title title="historypage" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qrc:///main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///jquery.js"></script>
... more js function ...</head>
<body onresize="ResizeSignal();" onscroll="ResizeSignal(); OnscrollSignal();">
</body>
</html>
```

Qt load page code.

```
page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("qrc:///my.html"));
```

Comment: Can you open ur local html file in browser? QWebView should be able to load correct html file because it can even load other famous websites.

Comment: No in browser my html file not display, because i inject some object(page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString("obj"), m_model);) to my page and after that is loading.Without this object i don't know how to debug my page and look work it, but in previous version this page work properly.

Comment: This problem was resolved,in my html-page mistake in the title.The tag <title title="page" /> invalid for latest qt version, you must close tags according standarts html markup <title title="page"></title>